# 'Cell' object has not attribute 'copy_format_from'

Tags: excel, datanitro

The datanitro docs illustrate how you can copy formatting from one cell to another:

> > > Cell("A2").copy_format_from(Cell("A1"))

However, this is generating the following error:

> > > AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'copy_format_from'

Any ideas what is going on?

https://datanitro.com/docs/cell.html

Comment: Where are you trying to run this code? From the Python interpreter?

Comment: Try `CellRange("A2").copy_format_from(Cell("A1"))`

Comment: -Portland Runner: that suggestion results in the same error.  I tried running the code from both the datanitro shell and incorporating it into a python script that was then run via the datanitro ribbon from within excel

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of DataNitro? Try downloading and installing the latest binary (you can get it [here](https://datanitro.com/pro/auth/login)) and see if that helps.